# jQuery Google Map adding marker with styled image icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am adding a marker in google map using jquery mobile gmap plugin. I want to add style (class) into that. How is it possible? Normal image icon is working fine -

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'disableDefaultUI':false, 'zoom':15, 'callback': function() {
        var self = this;
        clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0983425, -118.3267434);
        self.addMarker({
            position: clientPosition,
            icon: 'images/myImage.png',
            bounds: false
        });
        self.get('map').panTo(clientPosition);
    }});
```

I am using circular image icon using following style, which works fine with normal image -

```
.icon_circle {
width:50px;
height:50px;
border-radius:100%;
border: 1px solid #07c;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #07c;
}
```

I want to use same style with marker icon.

Comment: What are you asking for? You want a circle icon for a marker? Why not replace the .png image that you are using? Why not use SVG?

Comment: First - there is not just a one file which I'll replace with one png. These are multiple files provided by client, so creating a styled png for each is not feasible. In future that'll be used as dynamic image names stored on server. Second - Those images would be camera taken image as well. User will take picture, that will be uploaded on server and fetched back as markers. I know that there are options like cropping uploaded image or image-data using PHP - but I was just looking for simpler option. Because my style is already created in CSS for other images.

Answer (score 0):

**Original:**

Often we will inspect the resulting HTML to get the class name (or at least a path to it) and write our CSS towards that.

If we found something called .gmap_icon_container, we would may be able to do:

```
.gmap_icon_container img {
  /* css here */
}
```

---

**Edit:**

It's kind of tough to access google map markers by crawling through the inspector as I suggested (although possible, it won't be reliable)

However... if you really want to style these, you *could* (I haven't tested this) set a custom icon using the javascript google map API, and then access that and set a class on it via JQUERY, and style that class with CSS.

To set markers via google api:

```
var iconBase = 'http://myserver.com/images/mapicons';
var icons = {
  me: {
    icon: iconBase + 'mylocation.png'
  },
  others: {
    icon: iconBase + 'otherlocations.png'
  },
};

function addMarker(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });
}
```

To get the class via JQUERY and set its class:

```
$("img[src='http://myserver.com/images/mapicons/mylocation.png']")[0].addClass( "mylocation_icon" )
$("img[src='http://myserver.com/images/mapicons/otherlocations.png']").addClass( "otherlocations_icon" )
```

and css:

```
.mylocation_icon { /*css here*/ }
.otherlocations_icon { /*css here*/ }
```

Comment: I could not find that class. But let's assume that I find that somehow. Now there will be dynamic numbers of markers. I need self location marker with one style and other's location marker with different styles. But all other location marker style will be similar to each other. Will above method work in that scenario?

Comment: I would definitely NOT do that.

Comment: Ha! Yeah, it can be fairly dodgy, especially when things may change on the google map side, but in terms of getting to the item you want for styling, it may be the only way. And, no you will not see "gmap_icon_container".. that was just an example. See my edit for more suggestions.